# Excel - row formula not working with indirect reference

Tags: excel, reference, excel-indirect

[click to show example of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwP2b.jpg)

I want to get it to show row(1:1) (aka 1), row(2:2), and so on to row(11:11) (aka 11) in A2 to K2. Indirect(A1) = Indirect(1) = ref error; how do I get my row formula to accurately refer to the values in cells A1:K1?

Comment: what i'm trying to do is drag across row(1:1) -> row(n:n) horizontally.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please explain further what it is exactly which you are trying to achieve?

the indirect function will return an error as it's expecting a string containing a range, and 1 is not a range.

indirect(A1) would work if A1 contained a string such as "A2" or "B2:B7" or even referencing another sheet "Sheet2!C21"

Another way it works is to build the string and use the values in other cells also, for example if A1 contained the number 5, and you wrote 
=indirect("B" & A1)
you would return the value in B5

You could nest the indirect inside the row command, so for example
=ROW(INDIRECT("A1")) would return 1.

Hope this helps, if not if you could give a little more detail I can provide a better answer for you

Comment: thanks for trying to answer but it's not what I'm looking for. If you do =row(indirect("A1")), you're not able to drag it across to K2; it'll stay as "A1". If you click on the image link I attached, it should help clarify what I'm looking for. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: haven't logged on here in ages so didn't see your reply, hopefully this answer is not too late, try the following

=ROW(INDIRECT(A1&":"&A1))